# Docker: Artifactory CE-C++ behind a reverse proxy (using traefik)

Tags: docker, artifactory, traefik

I'm trying to run Artifactory (Artifactory CE-C++, V7.6.1) behind a reverse proxy (Traefik v2.2, latest).
Both are official unaltered docker-images. For starting them up I'm using docker-compose.

My artifactory-yml-file (*docker-compose.yml*) uses the following traefik-configuration:

```
image: docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-cpp-ce
[...]
lables:
  - "traefik.enable=true"
  - "traefik.http.routers.artifactory.rule = Host(`localhost`) && PathPrefic(`/artifactory`)"
  - "traefik.http.routers.artifactory.middlewares=artifactory-strippprefix"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.artifactory-strippprefix.strippprefix.prefixes=/"
  - "traefik.docker.network=docker-network"
```

*Note: My network docker network is just a simple docker network (external). I have this still in there because of traefik v1*

My artifactory is **accessible at the beginning** over `http://localhost/artifactory/`, but only when starting up. As soon as artifactory wants me to redirect to its UI, it takes me to `http://localhost/ui/` instead of (I guess?) `http://localhost/artifactory/ui/`, which is invalid.

I'm seeking either for a feature to tell artifactory it should account the prefix `/artifactory` when forwarding or a possibility in traefik to alter artifactory’s forward -response in a way that the forward-url matches the path.

---

I'm also using Jenkins with traefik, there it was as simple as adding

```
JENKINS_OPTS: "--prefix=/jenkins"
```

Answer (score 0):

The Artifactory CE-C++ opens up two ports: 8081 and 8082. I suggest your reverse proxy points to the format port 8081, does it? Whereas the UI endpoint is AFAIK served on 8082. Did you try this port?